# Displaying account operations by dates

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to verify the operations done in an account at a particular period of time by asking the user to enter account number and the date range, but each time I run it I have the error "type mismatch"

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
    Call search
End Sub

Sub search()
    Dim strCriteria, strCount, task As String

    Me.Refresh
    If IsNull(Me.compte_hist) Or IsNull(Me.date_deb) Or IsNull(Me.date_fin) Then
        MsgBox "s'il vous plaît assurez-vous que tous les champs sont remplis", vbInformation, "Date Range Required"
        Me.compte_hist.SetFocus
    Else
        strCriteria = "([Date_operation]>= #" & Me.date_deb & "# And [Date_operation] <= #" & Me.date_fin & "#)"
        strCount = "[Compte]=#" & Me.compte_hist & "#"
        task = "select * from Operations where Operations  (" & strCriteria & ")" And " (" & strCount & ") order by [Date_operation]" 
        DoCmd.ApplyFilter task
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Friendly note, `strCriteria` and `strCount` are variants. see the [doc](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/877/declaring-variables/2957/dim#t=201607281239547850873)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
strCriteria = "([Date_operation]>= #" & Format(Me.date_deb, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "# And [Date_operation] <= #" & Format(Me.date_fin, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#)"
strCount = "[Compte]=" & Me.compte_hist
task = "select * from Operations where (" & strCriteria & ") And  (" & strCount & ") order by [Date_operation]"
Me.RecordSource = task
```

Also you can apply filter only:

```
strCriteria = "([Date_operation]>= #" & Format(Me.date_deb, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "# And [Date_operation] <= #" & Format(Me.date_fin, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#)"
strCount = "[Compte]=" & Me.compte_hist
task = "(" & strCriteria & ") And  (" & strCount & ")"
Me.Filter = task
Me.FilterOn = True
```

If account number is not numeric, use quotes:

```
strCount = "[Compte]='" & Me.compte_hist & "'"
```